# Spring Boot doesn't load javascript file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

After Spring starts, I open my ajax.html page, but nothing happens. There is no error message, the js file just doesn't start. If I write javascript-code in ajax.html, it works normally.

ajax.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="webjars/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fill">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

project structure

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhocU.png)

Comment: If I click to src="...main.js" in ajax.html, I move to js file

Comment: did you try F12 and see any errors in console tab?

Comment: yes, but there is not errors

Comment: Been there, done that: You're sure, the folder is `resources/static/js` and not `resources/static.js`? IntelliJ sometimes doesn't help here

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and solved it in the following way:

I added the `addResourceHandlers` to my Java config file:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/views/", ".jsp");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**", "/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/", "classpath:/static/js/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

`resources` folder contains a `static/js` and a `static/css` folder both containing the specified files.

Hope it gives you help!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Spring boot, you don't have to add "/static/**" folder in your url. You should miss "/static/" and write like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

And make sure that if you are using spring securiry, you should permit All to access "/js/**" path :

```
http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers( "/js/**", "/css/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the resource handler for webjars? See: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-webjars

`../static/js/main.js` seems wrong. In spring boot, resources in the static directory are referred to without "static" in the URL, so just `/js/main.js`.

Other than that, are the scripts being loaded? What does the Network tab for the Console say?

Comment: resource handler I didn't add yet, but I'll try to do this now

Comment: looks like he doesn't have a static directory, but a static.js directory.  and yes, /js/main.js would be the path

Comment: i also move ajax.js from resource/static/js/ to resource/js/ but it doesn't help